# How do I add to the MESSAGES list in the Visual Studio Error List window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

#error shows in errors, #warning in warnings. How can I make a line of text appear in the messages filter of the Error List window?

To clarify:

If I place the following line within a C# code file, it will generate an error on build, and that error will appear in the Error List window if I switch the errors on (like tabs above the list, there are buttons to toggle *Errors*, *Warnings*, and *Messages*).

```
#error This will cause a divide by zero
```

The same can be done to inject warnings into the build output:

```
#warning This might produce a NullReference exception
```

What would I place in the C# code file to have a message like that appear in the *Messages* list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer: You can't.

If you want to communicate with the builder of your code, use warnings or errors as these appear in all builds, not just in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4):

You may use TasksList. On the View menu, point to Other Windows and then click Task List. 
The Task List is displayed.
In the Categories list, click Comments. 
The Comments list displays the comment text and appears there whenever you open and edit the code file. You can click any Task List comment to activate the file in the Code Editor and jump to the line of code that the comment marks. You may use //TODO, //HACK, //UNDONE or you specified custom comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008022.aspx

I stopped by this question because I was searching to do the same from my AddIn written in C# for Visual Studio 2010.

After a couple of minutes I finally got the answer in that link!

Comment: +1 but that's way more work than seems acceptable. I'd rather use the INFO approach in that case. But thank you for the info, maybe someone can turn that into a plugin that converts #message lines from code.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what you are asking? You basically want to see those errors and warnings displayed?

This may sound very basic but:
1) Make sure your Error List is displayed fully by making the window bigger so you see the headers Description, File, Line...
2) Click on the # Errors and # Warnings buttons at the top.

Comment: I've tried to clarify my question with the latest edit. I hope that helps.

Comment: He means he wants them to appear in the "Messages" tab, not the Errors or Warnings tab (i.e. informational only, doesn't affect the build process.)

Answer (score 0):

We tend to do what necrostaz suggested.  We've defined our own INFO tag so we can put `// INFO This is a message.`

It would be good to find a way to generate an informational message, though.